# Can you find latitude and longitude coordinates along a route with the Gmaps4Rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am trying to find the latitude and longitude at specific intervals along a driving route. I found a JavaScript library called epoly.js that can do that. Is there way to get these coordinates on the backend using the Gmap4Rails gem?